# How can I compile a simple less code to css using VS2012 with Web Essentials?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, less

I have the following less code:

```
.aa {
    > {
        li { color: red;}
    }
}
```

When I run this in visual studio 2012 with the latest web essentials it tells me there's a compiler error on line 2.  Is this correct? I think it's valid less. Wondering why it does not compile to CSS. Note that this is the same syntax as code generated with css2less.cc. I just reduced the number of lines:

```
.favorites {
    > {
        li:hover {

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that is valid LESS syntax. Having the `>` selector by itself is not valid for a code block definition. You need to put the selector that follows with it:

```
.aa {
    > li {
        color: red;
    }
}
```